# How to add fields in the WordPress editor?

Tags: plugins, custom-field, editor

how to add fields in the WordPress editor?

I know there is a need to add persnalized fields in the editor but I want to save other information such as custom checkboxes

Any idea to put a textarea and checkbox in the wordpress editor?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you would find Advanced Custom Fields as a useful plugin in order to easily drop these in.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/